# Store value in Array Int in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, integer

How to store the resultant print in an Array of Integer. I try to append the value in empty array but in the print it shows me empty. Below is the swift code till what i have done.

```
var num = [Int]()
            var filterMenId = ""
            if let indexPath = self.colEat.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first{
                filterMenId = self.arrayMeal[indexPath.row].id.description
                let convert = Int(filterMenId) // Here i am getting the value, eg: 32
                print(num.append(convert!)) // Here i try to append but shows me empty
```

Comment: That correct. `Array.append` returns `void`, which is then printed. You may want to call `append` before the `print` statement and then just `print(num)` or `print (convert!)`,  depending on your needs

Comment: Surely it printed `()`, didn't it?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I want to print value after append

Comment: @Sweeper i want to see value not ()

Comment: I know you want to see the value, but saying "it shows empty" is misleading here, as `()` is definitely not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` *changes* the array by adding an element to the end of the array *only*. It does not produce a value.

`print` takes a *value* and prints it. Well, `append` does not produce a value, so `print(num.append(convert!))` prints `()`, which is a representation of "nothing"

More technically speaking, `append` returns `Void`, which is a typealias for an empty tuple `()`. The string representation of an empty tuple is, unsurprisingly, `()`.

If you want to print the array that would be produced if `convert` is added to `num`:

```
print(num + [convert!])
```

Note that this does not change `num`.

If you want to add `convert` to `num`, and then print `num` to show what elements it has after the change, you need two lines:

```
num.append(convert!)
print(num)
```