# Inserting element in [String] array changes its type

Tags: swift

```
struct Numbers {
    var list: [String] = [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    ]
    
    func returnList() -> [String] {
        var sortedList: [String] = self.list.sorted()
        var finalList: [String] = sortedList.insert("four", at: 0)
        return finalList
    }
}
```

finalList is inferred to be a () instead of [String]. If I specify the type [String] I get the message:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type '[String]'

Why on earth?

Comment: Because `insert` returns `Void` aka `()` and modifies the array inplace? Just remove the `finalList` variable and return `sortedList`.

Comment: See [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66452912/5133585) about `append` rather than `insert`, or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66649002/5133585) about `subtract`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve misunderstood the error message.

The problem is that `sortedList.insert` does not return a value. (We express this by saying it returns `()`.) Hence it cannot be assigned to `finalList: [String]`, for the simple reason that it is *not* a `[String]`.

So just change

```
var sortedList: [String] = self.list.sorted()
var finalList: [String] = sortedList.insert("four", at: 0)
return finalList
```

To

```
var sortedList: [String] = self.list.sorted()
sortedList.insert("four", at: 0)
return sortedList
```

Comment: I grant that it can be a little confusing knowing which Swift methods return a value and which ones operate directly on a mutable target. Your code exemplifies both.